# Can I use Azure Email Communication Service as KeyCloak email provider?

Tags: azure, smtp, keycloak

I created an Azure Email Communication Service and I connected my domain to it and verified the domain, added SPF and DKIM1 and DKIM2 and all are verified.

I also have a KeyCloak instance running inside a docker container. And I want to provide a transactional email provider for it for sending **verification** and **password reset** emails.

However, I can't find a place in my Azure Portal to extract information regarding the SMTP parameters.

Can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no SMTP connection enabled by default.
For getting one you need to register an app in entra, and connect it to communication service (which also should be created), then you can fetch smtp credentials..
[image]
Follow the next guides:

[Quickstart: How to create authentication credentials for sending emails using SMTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/email/send-email-smtp/smtp-authentication)

[Create a Microsoft Entra application and service principal that can access resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/howto-create-service-principal-portal)